# place a laravel blade view inside a js var

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I am working on an application that has a custom model that works like this:

```
openFastModal(content);
```

I tried to use a blade to get the content:

```
var content =  '{!! view('forms.help') !!}'
```

This does not work, The content variable get rendered wrong

[image]

How can I add the content of a blade into a javascript variable as a string?

Comment: please do not do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include your file using backtick

```
`{!! view('forms.help') !!}`
```

Or 
replace newline characters with space in forms.help

the backtick version will work on newer browser that support es6 syntax although right now all major browser support it [check brower support](https://caniuse.com/#search=template%20literal)

but if you want to support old browser you should replace newline characters with space in your forms.help